# Help me see if I understand this RLC circuit

Tags: switches, passive-networks, homework

[image]
**The switch closes at t=0**

**I need to determine the current and the voltage of Capacitor at t=0.25s**

at t<0 the switch is open there is no current and no voltage

**at t=0 the switch closes the current starts flowing, the current that enters the RC part I called I1 as it is defined by R1**

I1=E/R1=100/2500=0.04A

**the current will go into the CAPACITOR because less resistance? anyway until the CAPACITOR get boosted to its voltage no current will go thru the R2**

**when the voltage is reached on the CAPACITOR the current starts flowing thru R2 and we can now get the total current I**

**Rtotal will be calculated as series resistance because iC=C du/dt and once there is no voltage change in time the current stops flowing thru the CAPACITOR**

I=E/Rtotal=100/5000=0.02A

**I can now get the voltage that the CAPACITOR needed to reach by using R2 as they are in parallel and therfor share voltage values**

V2=I*R2=0.02*2500=50V

V2=VC=50V

now if the CAPACITOR is being "charged" the **voltage grows** and the **current passing thru it(I1) falls** with time

**vC(0)=50*(1-e^(-0/tau))=50V for t=0**

**iC(0)=0.04(e^(-0/tau))=0.04A**

tau=Rtotalpar*C=1250*100*10^-6=0.125

**vC(0.25)=50*(1-e^(-0.25/0.125))=43.23V for t=0.25s**

**iC(0.25)=0.04(e^(-0.25/0.125))=0.005A**

Comment: Hint: combine E, R1 and R2 into the equivalent voltage source and series resistance. This will simplify the maths greatly.

Comment: You might also enjoy [MathJAX](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) which is supported on this site. You can also use HTML `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments).

Comment: What specific doubts or problems do you have? Honestly, this looks fine to me. Minor issue: .005A is a bit too much rounding, I'd write it as 5.41mA.

Comment: @make2r -- I thought this question looked really familiar. Thank you for adding the component values to the schematic, much easier to read this time around. As Transistor mentioned, MathJax is really helpful for formatting the body of the text. If you need an example, hit the edit button on your previous question that I formatted to see how it works. It is very easy for a potential answerer to get dissuaded by the excessive bold and poor formatting.

Comment: just wanted to see if its correct

Comment: This analysis is difficult to follow, and probably incorrect. Use a Thevenin equivalent circuit.

Comment: what is `CAPACITOR get boosted to its voltage`? ... what voltage is that?

Comment: @Chu: the analysis and the result look perfectly correct to me. A bit unorthodox but still correct. Start with the initial state and move exponentially to the steady state. Poke in the time and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The orthodox way would be via **transfer function/Laplace transformation**.  Just a few hints:

U_c(s) = E(s)*Z(s) / (Z(s) + R_2).

E(s) is the transformed step function, Z is the parallel complex resistance of C and R2, s is the complex frequency.

The step function's Laplace Transformation is 1/s.

.

(Some easy algebraic calculation in the frequency domain)

.

.

The result if re-transformed (look up tables, f.e. Bronstein-Semendjajew) into the time domain will be the same like the vC(t) mentioned at the end in the question.

The current can be calculated in the frequency domain by dividing U_c(s) by the complex resistance of C. Then another re-transformation/look up is needed.

Those familiar with the **Tellegen theorem** could simplify the algebraic calculation.